# How to convert CLOB to CHAR datatype in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

For ETL Purpose, I need to convert DB records into flat-files. For that, I have to convert all the records as CHAR. In that table, it's having few columns with CLOB datatype. So, I tried the following functions:

```
DBMS.LOBS_SUBSTR(column_name, Length(column_name))
```

> Error: ORA-06502 Pl/sql: numeric value error: character string buffer
>   too small ORA-06512: at line 1
>   06502. 00000 - "PL/SQL: numeric or value error ℅s"

Comment: Please clarify your question. First, are you sure you want to convert to CHAR and not to VARCHAR2? Are all your values the same length? And then, what do you mean by "it should not be limited to the length of characters..." - the ONLY data type that does NOT have a length limit is CLOB, that's the only reason it was introduced in the first place.

Comment: I will edit my answer. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Also: If you have tried DBMS.LOBS_SUBSTR, that should give you a different error (such as, there is no such function). If you find it difficult to copy what GurV wrote, use "copy" and "paste" editing. If in fact you used the correct function, DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR and you got an error, it is definitely **not** due to `null`s in the column; those would work perfectly fine.

Comment: Please check the error, in the description. If null is not the reason why I am getting these error.

Comment: @Vignesh please post the full code which you are using.

Comment: it's probably because you assigning the converted value to a smaller length char variable

Comment: select dbms_lob.substr(work_order_xml, length(work_order_xml)) from WO_Task_Card

Comment: Very likely because at least one of the input strings is longer than 4000 characters. "Character buffer string too small" means the input is longer than the memory buffer (which should be 4000 characters).

Comment: Yes.. That might be the reason. I can easily mention the range as 4000. But, I want to pull out exact records, without missing single things. Is there any other way to do this? Null is not an issue here

Comment: what do you want to do with it after pulling out? extract it in a file?send it to a web application?

Comment: For datawarehousing.. converted flat file is given as source in ETL tool for landing purpose. For that, we should extract the data as it is in DB.

Comment: There are various tools for exporting Oracle DB data to flat files, none of which require you to convert CLOB to character data type "manually". I am not familiar with them (not my specialty), but you will get more help here on Stack Overflow if you remove this question and post a different one: "How to export data including CLOBs to flat file" or similar. (That question will likely be "closed as duplicate" since I am sure it has been asked before, but that will point you to older, similar questions with the answers you need.) You may also try Google-ing the same first. Good lluck!

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much, both mathguy and GurV! I'm closing this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DBMS_LOB.substr()`

```
select DBMS_LOB.substr(col, 4000) from table;
```

Also, from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999349), restrictions are as:

> For fixed-width n-byte CLOBs, if the input amount for SUBSTR is
>   greater than (32767/n), then SUBSTR returns a character buffer of
>   length (32767/n), or the length of the CLOB, whichever is lesser. For
>   CLOBs in a varying-width character set, n is the maximum byte-width
>   used for characters in the CLOB

Comment: I edited my description. I had used what you mentioned here. The error is because of null values..

Comment: @VigneshKiswanth  -  no, it isn't.

Comment: For your reference, I have edited description with type of error I got.

Comment: What's the point of selecting a substring equal to the length of the original string? Did you mean `dbms_lob.substr(col, 4000)`?

Comment: @mathguy Yes, sorry. I adjusted what the OP gave, didnt notice it